# Como mostrar numero sin comas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda tengo el siguiente numero `33,003,567.564`y quisiera convertir a este numero en un numero sin comas pero si con punto decimal es decir:
Obtener algo como esto:

```
33003567.564
```

Y que esto se aplique con cualquier cantidad sin importar el numero de comas.
He buscado utilizando fomat pero no funciona

Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a suponer que todos esos números los tienes en un string

```
numeros.replace(",","")
```

Si los tienes en una lista

```
nuevo = ''.join(str(n) for n in numeros)
```